# Re-Authentication using Retrofit, RxJava and Observable.share?

Tags: java, android, authentication, retrofit, rx-java

The premise:

1. We use session tokens that expire after 3 hours
2. I have to use a special call called `auth`
3. Currently, when a session token expires, we do not preemptively refresh it, but instead attempt the call and if that call returns `401-UNAUTHORIZED` we call `auth` and retry the call. It works, but it isn't pretty
4. We're using Retrofit1 and RxJava1 (updating is currently not an option)

I would like to change it up in such a way, where I would check whether I need to refresh the token BEFORE I make the call.

I want to achieve that by chaining Observables and sharing the Auth-Observable between calls

Think like this:

1. Check if the SessionToken is about to expire or already expired
2. Start Auth-Call (returns an Observable)
3. Chain my call into the Auth-Call Observable
4. when another call happens and sees that the sessiontoken is close to expiring, check if there is an ongoing Auth-Call. If there is, chain the new call into Auth-Call

---

1st question: Is this actually a smart idea?
2nd question: Is this actually possible?
3rd question: How the hell do I do this?

Comment: I actually think that the way it works now is fine. Simple and clear.

Comment: it has some nasty side-effects. for one, you need to create a global error handler, unless you want to do it manually in ~60 calls. the errorhandler forces you to use interface-implementations, instead of giving you a simple observable, which turns testing into a nightmare because you can't use mockito anymore and have to mock EVERYTHING yourself

Comment: I can't tell regarding mocking. However, I disagree on Retrift Error handling being a _nasty side effect_. We don't know the project, so we can't give in depth suggestions.

Comment: @MrTorgue have you solved your issue ?

Comment: I think I did, I'll post the result shortly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick to this was using a Singleton Observable

```
Observable<AuthResponse> mAuthSingleton = retrofit.authenticate()
    .doOnNext( response -> saveSessionToken(response.getSessionToken())
    .share();


Observable<AuthResponse> getAuthCallWhenNecessary(){
    if(sessionToken == null ||sessionToken.isAboutToExpire())
        return mAuthSingleton;
    else
        return Observable.just(new AuthResponse());
}

Observable<WhateverResponse> getWhatever(){
    return getAuthCallWhenNecessary().flatMap(response -> retrofit.getWhatever());
}
```

your calls don't care whether the AuthResponse, they get when calling `getAuthCallWhenNecessary`, is a real one, they only care that they get a response-object from Auth

Here's my (kinda) documented work-sample: https://gist.github.com/TormundsMember/ebcb3782b14477a3d5b72e898929fe61

Comment: Thx, for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the combinaison of [repeatWhen](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#repeatWhen(rx.functions.Func1)) operator and [delay](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#delay(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) operator.

After the delay of token expiration , re-subscribe to your observable to get the new token.

Hope this helps.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: would be another possible solution, but having a long-running observable doesn't sound pretty

Comment: Yes i understand , but i think it is not a long-running observable, it's "just" subscribe to the same observable each n time, but once the value is emited , the subscription is consumed. The main issue of my suggestion is, i think, memory leak if the application is killed or whatever

Answer (score 0):

What I did in my case might be a bit overkill but it works - I wrapped all Retrofit interfaces with my own proxy class:

- Create your own proxy of your Retrofit interface with `Proxy.newProxyInstance`
- The proxy creates the Retrofit implementation with `Retrofit.Builder()`
- In the proxy's `public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args)` call the actual Retrofit implementation, before this call you can check if the token was valid or not, if not, refresh the token and call the Retrofit method implementation in `switchMap()`
- If the retrofit call fails because of 401, you can use `resultObservable.retryWhen(errorCheck)` to check for this error, refresh the access token and call the Retrofit method implementation again.
- (I also stored the result in a `BehaviorSubject` and returned this subject whenever a part of my app requested for the result (by calling an interface method), and I only refreshed the result from network when a separate `refresh()` call was issued)